# Predicate in filtering

Tags: java, lambda

```
 private List<BaseIcon> filterIconsToChangeByPositions(List<BaseIcon> baseIcons, List<Integer> positions) {
    return baseIcons.stream()
                    .filter(baseIcon -> pred(positions))
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());
}

private Predicate<BaseIcon> pred(List<Integer> positions) {
    return baseIcon -> positions.stream().anyMatch(pos -> pos == baseIcon.getPositionOnGameField());
}
```

не могу понять почему не компилится данныек код ведь типо пишет что у лмбд плохой тип

Answer (score 0):

Вы пишете в фильтре ещё одну лямбду вызывающую вашу функцию. Просто передайте в него её.

```
.filter(pred(positions))
```

Comment: Ведь filter принимает предикат, а функция pred как раз отдает его, ведь это тоже самое что filter(baseIcon -> positions.stream().anyMatch(pos -> pos == baseIcon.getPositionOnGameField()))

Comment: Вот так выглядит полный вариант вашей функции в фильтре: `.filter((baseIcon) -> {return pred(positions);})` фильтр ожидает что ему отдадут функцию возвращающую булево значение. А Вы ему отдаёте вместо него ещё одну лямбду. Чтобы вызвать функцию, которую вы возвращаете из `pred`, нужно обратиться к методу её функционального интерфейса: `.filter(baseIcon -> pred(positions).test(baseIcon))`